# DBCC FREEPROCCACHE along with Re-Organise Index maintenance task

Tags: sql-server-2014

While creating Index maintenance plan in SQL Server, they have also added execute T-SQL statement DBCC FREEPROCCACHE. Is this beneficial, or are there any side-effects?

Comment: I don't see any benefit index maintenance would get from DBCC command. The side effect is that the plans stored for procedures would be invalidated and new plan would have to be created when proc runs next time. I would advise you to remove that statement. I don't see any use

Comment: it sounds like they are taking a sledge hammer approach in getting all new execution plans created regardless of whether a new plan is any better than the old plan.  Unfortunately, they blew away perfectly good execution plans that were accessing tables not involved in the index maint.

Answer (score 3):

The [DBCC FREEPROCCACHE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174283.aspx) command is not beneficial (for index maintenance), and should not be executed in this context.

It flushes the plan cache, which causes all query plans to be recompiled when they are executed again.

If there's no way to turn that setting off manually, it is better to use recommended third-party index maintenance scripts, such as those by [Ola Hallengren](http://ola.hallengren.com/) or [Minionware](http://minionware.net/).

**EDIT**: For an index re-organize, you should add a step to update statistics as well, because they are not updated automatically. This step alone has the same effect as invalidating stale plans, without the negative of flushing the entire cache. The above third-party maintenance solutions include a step to only update statistics that need updating.